# IBM Maximo Query help using MatRecTrans table

Tags: maximo

I'm trying to build a query that displays a list of part item #'s in Inventory(Tr) but only ones that were received at least 12 months prior to current date AND haven't been issued to an assett in 12 months. But I can't figure out how to filter out results that are within the previous 12 months using the MatRecTrans table and TransDate filter tables.

Here is what I have so far...

```
status in (
    select value from synonymdomain
    where domainid ='ITEMSTATUS' 
    and maxvalue not in ('OBSOLETE')
    and exists (
        select 1 from invbalances
        where invbalances.itemnum = inventory.itemnum
        and invbalances.location = inventory.location
        and invbalances.siteid = inventory.siteid 
        and invbalances.itemsetid = inventory.itemsetid 
        and invbalances.curbal != 0
    )
    and lastissuedate < current date - 12 month
)
```

MATRECTRANS.ISSUETYPE is the name of the Table column that I want to include only 'RECEIPT' issuetype

And MATRECTRANS.TRANSDATE is the Table column that I want to see only item's that have transaction dates that are current date-12 months.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Restructured the query to the suggested format from the website.

Comment: It would be better if you could include your whole query instead of just part of it.
Also, it's much easier to diagnose your problem if you include the information from your linked images as Text in the question so that it's possible to cut and paste it.

Comment: Your query seems to be overcomplicated. It's usually much better to use joins rather than subqueries. Because I can't see your table definitions, I can't suggest much here but at least `and maxvalue not in ('OBSOLETE')` could be replaced with the much simpler `AND maxvalue <> 'OBSOLETE'`.

Comment: This is the whole query, at least the portion that the "WHERE CLAUSE" allows me to view within Maximo. The information is in text form. It's the MATRECTRANS.ISSUETYPE and MATRECTRANS.TRANSDATE, I just included images for reference.

Comment: This was actually a pre-loaded query that was built on the request of my company when we switched to Maximo, but the creator of the query must not have been told the complete end result desired as it's showing items that haven't been "issued" within 12 months, but doesn't ignore items that were just received into inventory recently.

Answer (score 0):

I've adjusted things a little, so they make more sense, and added the matrectrans condition you were looking for.

```sql
status in (
    select value from synonymdomain
    where domainid ='ITEMSTATUS' 
    and maxvalue not in ('OBSOLETE')
)
and exists (
    select 1 from invbalances
    where invbalances.itemnum = inventory.itemnum
    and invbalances.location = inventory.location
    and invbalances.siteid = inventory.siteid 
    and invbalances.itemsetid = inventory.itemsetid 
    and invbalances.curbal != 0
)
and lastissuedate < current date - 12 month
and exists (
    select 1 from matrectrans
    where itemnum = inventory.itemnum
    and tostoreloc = inventory.location
    and tositeid = inventory.siteid 
    and itemsetid = inventory.itemsetid 
    and transdate > current date - 12 month
    and issuetype in ( 
        select value from synonymdomain
        where domainid = 'ISSUETYP'
        and maxvalue = 'RECEIPT'
    )
)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll try it tomorrow and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Produces a System Message, " 
BMXAA6713E - The MBO fetch operation failed in the mboset with the SQL error code -206. The record could not be retrieved from the database. See the log file for more details about the error."

Comment: OK I was able to get it to not show an MBO Fetch message by changing some lines, but now I get a "No Records Found" message. If it helps, here is how the screens are navigated. When I run the original query a list populates (within invbalances I assume), but in order to view the matrectrans screen, I have to select an individual record and then select View Inventory Transactions, which opens (I believe) the MATRECTRANS table. Perhaps the hang-up is in order to access the MATRECTRANS I have to first access the "record table" but I don't know the name of that able.

Comment: I changed the "and tostoreloc..." to "fromstoreloc..." because it doesn't appear the "tostoreloc" is an option in the matrectrans table. Also corrected the domainid 'ISSUETYPE' that was missing the "E"

Comment: Also, here is the "Copy Link" of the "View Inventory Transactions" button:  Perhaps this will help accessing the correct table?       javascript: if(SCREENREADER && topLevelMenus['m74daaf83_ns_MC'].isNavItem('m74daaf83_ns_menu_INVTRANS_OPTION_a')){ setCurrentfocusFromId(event,'m74daaf83_ns_menu_INVTRANS_OPTION')};topLevelMenus['m74daaf83_ns_MC'].menuClick({"text":"View Inventory Transactions","id":"INVTRANS_OPTION","mxevent":"INVTRANS","target":"plustinv","event":"INVTRANS"});

Comment: The conditions like `where invbalances.itemnum = inventory.itemnum` in your query are expecting you to be using the query from the INVENTORY object, the main object of the INVENTOR application. Note that the first versions of Maximo suffered from "8 character" limitations in some places, hence the app being named INVENTOR (no Y) and the domain being ISSUETYP (no E).

Comment: Further to my previous comment, you could try replacing all the `inventory.` references with `:` to change from table references to substitution variables.

Comment: Well I made some progress today. I still am pulling way too many results that are less than a year old, and its seems to be because while referencing the transdate, it looks at the entire table for date records. So while a "< current date - 12 months", say last week, will be ignored for a singular transaction perhaps, if there are any other transactions within the table, maybe 13 months ago for the same record it still populates the result. So I googled for an answer to pull ONLY the most recent date and found LIMIT clauses or FETCH ONLY "value" results, but can't seem to get them to work.

Comment: In my case(maybe all) the most recent date is the top/first result.

Comment: Also it seems that the "where domainid = 'ISSUETYP' and maxvalue = 'RECEIPT' " may not even been necessary because the matrectrans table appears to be only RECEIPTS anyway. I've yet to verify that 100% so it may still be useful once I can get the rest of the query dialed in.

Comment: Preacher, thank you so much for your help. How would I include 'null' into the subquery below?
    and issuetype in ( 
        select value from synonymdomain
        where domainid = 'ISSUETYPE'
        and maxvalue = 'RECEIPT') *OR IS NULL*

Comment: `and (issuetype in ( select value from synonymdomain where domainid = 'ISSUETYPE' and maxvalue = 'RECEIPT') OR issuetype IS NULL)`